Calculating Discounts for Tax Included or Out the Door Pricing

Note: this question was answered in the Math SE.

I am trying to figure out how to properly calculate a product discount so a customer can pay a price agreed upon at checkout, including tax, with multiple taxes applied to different amounts of the item price. The price is unknown until checkout and is kind of a bargaining tactic. For instance:
Customer wishes to buy multiple items with a subtotal of $6,000. There is a 6% Sales Tax on all items and an additional 1% on the first $5000 of all items. Some of these items are below $5,000. One is above.



Item
Price
Quantity
Total
Amount Surtaxed
0.01 Surtax Amount
Pctg of Order Total




Thing 1
$100.00
1
$100.00
$100.00
$1.00
1.56%


Thing 2
$5,500.00
1
$5,500.00
$5,000.00
$50.00
85.74%


Thing 3
$400.00
1
$400.00
$400.00
$4.00
6.24%













Subtotal
$6,000.00







Base Sales Tax (6%)
$360.00







County Surtax (1%)
$55.00







Total Tax
$415.00







Order Total
$6,415.00






The customer wants to only pay $6,000 so we agree on that amount. Our store needs to ensure that sales taxes are paid on the order but, of course, we don't want to pay those taxes. So, we want to discount the each item according to its pctg of the total to get to a new subtotal which when the taxes are applied our new Order Total is exactly $6,000. The customer ends up paying the tax on lower priced items.
We've come up with a couple formulas for this and it works fine when we're only worried about a singular tax rate or just a single item. When we need to handle multiple tax rates and multiple items, we have a hard time getting the correct total.
I can post what we've tried but I'm afraid that will muddy the waters. We call this an "out the door" price.

Note that some municipalities explicitly forbid advertising "tax included" prices. You are free to charge prices which, after tax is added, will come out to nice round numbers... but you may have to post those non-rounded prices and trusted the customer will understand your intent. Also, since tax is computed on the total sale, to have the rounding work when multiple items are purchased you may have to price things in fractional currency, which may or may not be permitted. There is no answer that is correct everywhere. Check local ordinances.

Why would anyone want to forbid advertising tax included prices?

@keshlam, thank you. We're aware of the local laws regarding the taxes.

@DJClayworth: I have a theory but since it's only a guess... Suffice it to say the issue exists in some areas.

@keshlam It's comments, so feel free to tell me your guess. I won't hold you to it.

@DJClayworth: unless you set pre-tax prices down to an obscene number of digits of accuracy, the round off stops producing even numbers when you start buying more than one thing at a time. That gets you into having to prove that, for all possible combinations, the error is in the government's favor rather than in yours. Otherwise, as several bank frauds have shown, skimming a fraction of a penny from each transaction can start to add up to real money, and real tax fraud. I suspect that, where this is forbidden, they decided the cost of doing it right exceeded possible benefits.

Thanks. I think it's a silly reason (I come from a country where every price has to include tax.) But I asked and you answered. Thanks.

@DJClayworth Since when did Canada include GST/PST/HST in displayed prices? There's several reasons why: it makes traveling to seek a lower tax rate (going a city/county over in the US) less obvious; it enables nationwide price advertising; when one jurisdiction exempts something like food and medicine, they want to make sure it isn't eaten by the manufacturer. Canada and the US are basically the same in sales tax variance, Canada is 5-15%, US is 0-13.5%.

You are probably free to adjust discount price for each sale, as a negotiation with that particular customer, as long as the same deal is offered to all customers and whatever you do comes out at or below your advertised price. Just tweak numbers until it comes out to the right total.

@user71659 I'm British originally.

This sounds more like a [math.se] problem than a financial quesiton.

@Barmar, I asked over there as well and then someone closed question as "opinion based". https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4996870/finding-discounts-for-multiple-items-accounting-for-tax

Answered in Math SE. Please go there for the full details.
